# how to use fireAnbu in laravel 3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3, firephp

I've installed the bundle [fireAnbu](https://github.com/codenitive/laravel-fireanbu) in my local laravel 3 app, but I can't figure out how to use it! (feeling silly)

I've got `'fireanbu' => array('auto' => true),` in bundles.php and `'profiler' => true,` in fireanbu/config/fireanbu.php, and I've tried:

- `fireanbu::log('something');`
- `$fireanbu->log('something');`
- `FirePHP::log('something');`
- `$FirePHP->log('something');`
- `FB::log('something');`
- `$fb->log('something');`

I've had a look in fireanbu/start.php for clues, but I'm guessing :(

The best clue I've had so far is:

`Non-static method FirePHP::log() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

I've looked at http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm and it looks like fireanbu is using the OO API..

What am I doing wrong / how should I call it within my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no need to do anything. It would listen to event from Laravel's own Log class and attach it to FirePHP.

`Log::info('foo');` would just work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I also created a Laravel 4 version for this if anyone finds this thread looking for a L4 version (like I did, and in the absence of finding one created my own):
https://packagist.org/packages/p3in/firephp